# MongoDb Query Runs So Slow On .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a mongoDb query with compound index.

```js
{
  daySeq: 7942,
  ipType: 1,
  sessionStartTime: {
    $lt: ISODate('2023-07-31T23:00:00.000Z')
  },
  sessionUpdateTime: {
    $gt: ISODate('2023-07-31T22:00:00.000Z')
  }
}
```

i run this query with this index `daySeq_-1_ipType_-1_sessionStartTime_-1_sessionUpdateTime_-1`
and this is my explain result from mongodb compass when i executed query

```
"executionStats": {
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 392589,
    "executionTimeMillis": 24836,
    "totalKeysExamined": 680338,
    "totalDocsExamined": 392589,
    "executionStages": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "nReturned": 392589,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 23268,
      "works": 680338,
      "advanced": 392589,
      "needTime": 287748,
      "needYield": 0,
      "saveState": 1636,
      "restoreState": 1636,
      "isEOF": 1,
      "docsExamined": 392589,
      "alreadyHasObj": 0,
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "nReturned": 392589,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1441,
        "works": 680338,
        "advanced": 392589,
        "needTime": 287748,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 1636,
        "restoreState": 1636,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "keyPattern": {
          "daySeq": -1,
          "ipType": -1,
          "sessionStartTime": -1,
          "sessionUpdateTime": -1
        },
        "indexName": "daySeq_-1_ipType_-1_sessionStartTime_-1_sessionUpdateTime_-1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "daySeq": [],
          "ipType": [],
          "sessionStartTime": [],
          "sessionUpdateTime": []
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": 2,
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "daySeq": ["[7942, 7942]"],
          "ipType": ["[1, 1]"],
          "sessionStartTime": [
            "(new Date(1690844400000), new Date(-9223372036854775808)]"
          ],
          "sessionUpdateTime": [
            "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1690840800000))"
          ]
        },
        "keysExamined": 680338,
        "seeks": 287749,
        "dupsTested": 0,
        "dupsDropped": 0
      }
    },
    "allPlansExecution": [
      {
        "nReturned": 101,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 2,
        "totalKeysExamined": 101,
        "totalDocsExamined": 101,
        "executionStages": {
          "stage": "FETCH",
          "nReturned": 101,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 2,
          "works": 101,
          "advanced": 101,
          "needTime": 0,
          "needYield": 0,
          "saveState": 7,
          "restoreState": 7,
          "isEOF": 0,
          "docsExamined": 101,
          "alreadyHasObj": 0,
          "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned": 101,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
            "works": 101,
            "advanced": 101,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 7,
            "restoreState": 7,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "keyPattern": {
              "daySeq": -1,
              "ipType": -1,
              "sessionStartTime": -1,
              "sessionUpdateTime": -1
            },
            "indexName": "daySeq_-1_ipType_-1_sessionStartTime_-1_sessionUpdateTime_-1",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
              "daySeq": [],
              "ipType": [],
              "sessionStartTime": [],
              "sessionUpdateTime": []
            },
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
              "daySeq": ["[7942, 7942]"],
              "ipType": ["[1, 1]"],
              "sessionStartTime": [
                "(new Date(1690844400000), new Date(-9223372036854775808)]"
              ],
              "sessionUpdateTime": [
                "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1690840800000))"
              ]
            },
            "keysExamined": 101,
            "seeks": 1,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "dupsDropped": 0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nReturned": 18,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 108,
        "totalKeysExamined": 101,
        "totalDocsExamined": 101,
        "executionStages": {
          "stage": "FETCH",
          "filter": {
            "$and": [
              { "ipType": { "$eq": 1 } },
              {
                "sessionStartTime": {
                  "$lt": "2023-07-31T23:00:00.000Z"
                }
              },
              {
                "sessionUpdateTime": {
                  "$gt": "2023-07-31T22:00:00.000Z"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "nReturned": 18,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 108,
          "works": 101,
          "advanced": 18,
          "needTime": 83,
          "needYield": 0,
          "saveState": 1636,
          "restoreState": 1636,
          "isEOF": 0,
          "docsExamined": 101,
          "alreadyHasObj": 0,
          "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned": 101,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
            "works": 101,
            "advanced": 101,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 1636,
            "restoreState": 1636,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "keyPattern": {
              "daySeq": -1,
              "username": -1,
              "sessionId": -1
            },
            "indexName": "daySeq_-1_username_-1_sessionId_-1",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
              "daySeq": [],
              "username": [],
              "sessionId": []
            },
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
              "daySeq": ["[7942, 7942]"],
              "username": ["[MaxKey, MinKey]"],
              "sessionId": ["[MaxKey, MinKey]"]
            },
            "keysExamined": 101,
            "seeks": 1,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "dupsDropped": 0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

i know maybe its not that fast but i expect the close performance from .NET and i execute query on .net side with that way

```csharp
var filter = Builders < CdrDocumentModel > .Filter.And(
  Builders < CdrDocumentModel > .Filter.Eq("daySeq", daySeq),
  Builders < CdrDocumentModel > .Filter.Eq("ipType", 1),
  Builders < CdrDocumentModel > .Filter.Lt("sessionStartTime", BsonDateTime.Create(endDate.AddHours(3))),
  Builders < CdrDocumentModel > .Filter.Gt("sessionUpdateTime", BsonDateTime.Create(startDate.AddHours(3)))
);
var cdrList = await _cdrRepository.GetCollection().Find(filter)
  .Project(cdr => new CdrDocumentModel() {
    Username = cdr.Username,
      SessionId = cdr.SessionId,
      User = cdr.User,
  })
  .ToListAsync();
```

And it takes 3-4 min to return the cdr list. Is it makes sense or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It does make sense, the query planner shows the index is being utilized properly.

The main "problem" you have is that you're returning about 400k documents from this query. This is quite a lot of network traffic and in memory processing.
You can see that the actual execution time is only 24 seconds: `"executionTimeMillis": 24836,` this means the rest of the time (3.5m+) is wasted on overhead like network.

Unfortunately, Assuming you do want and need all 400k documents I can't think of a way of improving this too much.

I recommend doing the following actions:

1. Add a projection to only the fields you need, this will probably have negligent affect on performance unless your objects are really big and have a lot of redundant information in them.
2. If possible split this into multiple processes - kind of a map reduce approach, for example one process for each 10minutes of the hour. This is your best bet but i'm not sure you're application allows for it.